# hive : remove stuff from distributed cache

Tags: hadoop, hive, distributed-cache

I can add stuff to distributed cache via

```
add file largelookuptable
```

and then run a bunch of HQL.

now when I have a series of commands, like the following

```
add file largelookuptable1;
select blah from blahness using somehow largelookuptable1;
add file largelookuptable2;
select newblah from otherblah using largelookuptable2;
```

in this case `largelookuptable1` is unnecessarily available for the second query. is there a way I can get rid of it before the second query runs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Hive CLI, type:
delete file largelookuptable1;

Same thing applies to jars added to distributed cache.

Syntax (from Hive CLI):
Usage: delete [FILE|JAR|ARCHIVE]  []*